# How to disable http caching in applet

Tags: java, caching, applet, http-caching, japplet

**How can i disable http caching of all my http connections in my japplet?** I dont want any of my http (request/response)to be cached.Regardless of the user settings in control panel\java\Temporary File Settings. Applet is signed and compiled with java1.6.
I am using URLConnection.class and my request to an 3rd party web service is being cached.
ie:
I can see my request url in Java Cache Viewer. 
http://www.service.com?param1=232&param2=2323232 
Also i can find the responses in application ....users\data\sun\java\deployment\cache 
responseline1 
responseline2

Comment: So which libraries are you using? What kind of calls do you make and are now being cached? Is the applet self the thing that is being cached?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable caches using [URLConnection.setUseCaches(boolean)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setUseCaches%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to break caching is to add a random value to the url ala:

`String url = "http://www.example.com/?noCache=" + Math.Random();`